# What size should I have my navigationItem.titleView set to?

Tags: ios, swift, image-size, xcasset

I've been trying to put an image in my `titleView` in the navigation bar. The image keeps coming out way too blurry and I can't seem to understand why for the life of me.

Right now my images are 28x14 for the @1x, 56x28 for the @2x, 84x42 @3x and the frame of the `titleView` is 50x50. Should I be sizing the @1x 50px, @2x 100px and the @3x at 150px? Essentially, does the width and height of the image rely on the frame?

I'm not entirely sure how to go about this, any help would be appreciated. I am trying to have the image work for all iPhone sizes, 5,6 and 6 plus.

Code is below:

```
let imageView: UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    imageView.image = UIImage(named: "NavigationTitleLogo")

    self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
```

**Addition**

I'm also having the same issue with my MKAnnotationPin images.

Comment: The width and height of the image view should match the size of the @1x image - 28x14. Why would you make it 50x50 if the image is only 28x14?

Comment: The frame of the UIImageView is 50 w and 50 h. In my first try I did it as 28x14 so it can match the `navigationItem.leftItem`

Comment: Your image is blurry because the image view is scaling the 28x14 image up to 50x50. Either resize the image view, resize the image, or tell the image view not to scale the image.

Comment: How would I tell it not to scale? Is there a property?

Comment: Look at the `contentMode` property from `UIView`.

Comment: It's shifting the image to the left for some reason.

Comment: Depends on the content mode you set. Try `Center` or `AspectFit`.

Comment: So aspect fit works quite well, but it keeps my image pushed to the left because I have two right `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems`. Any way to still push it right? When I enter values for the x it doesn't move